# Ruby's Test::Unit 2.x testing - how do I generate an xml report?

Tags: ruby, testunit, xunit

I'm curious if it's possible to generate a file which holds tests' results? Perfectly, it will be a xUnit comportable xml file. Actually it's doesn't matter since it can parse it (html or whatever) and create an xml file by my own.

In other words, I would like to know how can I generate output tests' file for Ruby Test::Unit.

Comment: You could access the test output programmatically and work with it, right? Check out http://endofline.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/a-custom-testrunner-to-scratch-an-itch/ It shows how to customize the [Ruby TestRunner](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/UI/Console/TestRunner.html). The TestRunner gives you access to results of the tests.

Comment: It causes errors for some reason. Is it possible to run it via `rake` (Rails)?